# How to count the quantity of lowercase and uppercase letters in string?

Tags: swift, string, uppercase, lowercase

How can I count the quantity of lowercase and uppercase letters in string?

For example:

Input:

> Hello World

Output:

> 8 2

Because the input contains 8 lowercase, and 2 uppercase letters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I identify uppercase and lowercase characters in a string with swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268690/how-can-i-identify-uppercase-and-lowercase-characters-in-a-string-with-swift)

Comment: What should happen with white-space, symbols and other non-alphabet characters?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly from which version of Swift the following code compiles, but I tested it with Swift 5.4:

```
import Foundation

let testString = "ABCdefg"

let lowercase = testString.filter { $0.isLowercase }.count
let uppercase = testString.filter { $0.isUppercase }.count

print(lowercase, uppercase)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the built-in functionality of `Character` by using it's `isUppercase` and `isLowercase` attributes:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

var numOfUppercasedLetters = 0
var numOfLowercasedLetters = 0

for char in str {
    if char.isUppercase {
        numOfUppercasedLetters += 1
    } else if char.isLowercase {
        numOfLowercasedLetters += 1
    }
}

print(numOfUppercasedLetters, numOfLowercasedLetters)
```

See this thread for further information: [How can I identify uppercase and lowercase characters in a string with swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268690/how-can-i-identify-uppercase-and-lowercase-characters-in-a-string-with-swift)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `reduce(_:_:)` function of `String` like this:

```
var string = "Hello"

let (uppercase, lowercase) = string.reduce((0, 0)) { (result, character) -> (Int, Int) in
    if character.isUppercase {
        return (result.0 + 1, result.1)
    } else if character.isLowercase {
        return (result.0, result.1 + 1)
    }
    return result
}

print(uppercase, lowercase)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import Foundation

let  testString = "ABCdefg"
var uppercase = 0;
var lowercase = 0;

for character in testString {
    if character.isUppercase {
        uppercase += 1
    } else {
        lowercase += 1
    }
}

print(uppercase)
print(lowercase)
```